# SVN checkout mismatch issue in windows machine, working fine with linux

Tags: svn, checksum

I am trying to checkout a directory from svn with "svn co" command.

On Linux machine there is no issue and checkout is successful. While on a Windows machine I got the below error:-

```
svn: E200014: Checksum mismatch for '<filepath\filename.ext>':
   expected:  42e49c1c7ada074514f380cc522f612a
     actual:  ca35627d73f695d7dd8999b62a13323f
```

Tried below-

1. Creating fresh svn directory and then re-commits.
2. Shortening of file and directory names in svn.

Comment: Which SVN version is used? Is it possible that a file with the same name but different case exists in the repository?

Comment: Svn version 1.10.6(win10), version 1.7.14(linux). All files have unique names.

Comment: May be the files was modified by an installed virus scanner? Check your installed anti-virus solution if it had cleaned the file that does not match the checksum.

Comment: But there are some other similar directories as well which are easily checkout, without any error.